# Test method threw exception: Couldn't find window with title Calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, ui-testing

I have one problem for each UI test on my computer:[Test method threw exception: Couldn't find window with title Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCg7C.png). Of course, window is present and its name is "Calculator"(checked by inspect). The same situation is for others UI elements.

```
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using TestStack.White;
    using TestStack.White.Factory;
    using TestStack.White.UIItems;

    namespace UnitTestProject3
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
                using (var application = Application.Launch("Calc.exe"))
                {
                    var calculator = application.GetWindow("Calculator", InitializeOption.NoCache);

                    // do something with the application
                    var b7 = calculator.Get<Button>(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText("7"));
                    b7.Click();

                    application.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What could it be?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'm newcomer here and haven't enought reputation to upload images, it's ok

Comment: No, it isn't okay.  Share your code with us *as text*.  Read the link I posted.

Comment: it's not about the code, but I added it for you)

Comment: Is the application already launched before you run your test? Or some other applications which have a window named "Calculator"?

Comment: `application.Close();` this line is not needed, as your `using` already calls the `Close()` method of application at the end of the block

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: App didn't be launched before and there is only one window named "Calculator"

Comment: Yes, win 10, VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

Teststack White does not support UWP applications such as Calculator on Windows 10. For supporting UWP apps, you can use:

1. UIAComWrapper branch from white (partially working)
2. Switch to UIA3

More information [here](https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues/570#issuecomment-318156137)